# How to get a character without pausing the program

Tags: java, methods, char

I am making a pac man like program for my computer class, this is what I have so far...I wana add ghosts to the program. But I dont know how to make it so that the program doesnt stop everything and waits for the user to input. Like when I use c.getchar() it stops the programs and waits for users input. Is there anything else I can use that wont stop the program so its possible for a ghost to chase the pac man... please help!

```
// The "Pac_man" class.
import java.awt.*;
import hsa.Console;


public class Pac_man
{
    static Console c;           // The output console

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        c = new Console ();

        int outline_x = 189, outline_y = 99, body_x = 190, body_y = 100, eye_x = 208, eye_y = 106, outline_position_x = 26;
        int body_position_x = 30, p = 1, point_x = 0, point_y = 0, run_time = 0, score = 0, random_number, life = 3;
        char key_entered;

        background();
        redraw (score, outline_x, outline_y, outline_position_x, body_x, body_y, body_position_x, life);
        c.fillOval (eye_x, eye_y, 4, 4); // eye

        do 
        {
            key_entered = c.getChar();

            if (key_entered == 'd' || key_entered == 'D')
            {
                outline_x = outline_x + 10;
                body_x = body_x + 10;
                eye_x = eye_x + 10;
                outline_position_x = 26;
                body_position_x = 30;

                redraw (score, outline_x, outline_y, outline_position_x, body_x, body_y, body_position_x, life);
                c.fillOval (eye_x, eye_y-1, 4, 4); // eye
            }

             if (key_entered == 'a' || key_entered == 'A')
            {
                outline_x = outline_x - 10;
                body_x = body_x - 10;
                eye_x = eye_x - 10;
                outline_position_x = 206;
                body_position_x = 210;

                redraw (score, outline_x, outline_y, outline_position_x, body_x, body_y, body_position_x, life);
                c.fillOval (eye_x-6, eye_y, 4, 4); // eye

            }

            if (key_entered == 'w' || key_entered == 'W')
            {
                outline_y = outline_y - 10;
                body_y = body_y - 10;
                eye_y = eye_y - 10;
                outline_position_x = 116;
                body_position_x = 120;

                redraw (score, outline_x, outline_y, outline_position_x, body_x, body_y, body_position_x, life);
                c.fillOval (eye_x+2, eye_y+2, 4, 4); // eye
            }

            if (key_entered == 's' || key_entered == 'S')
            {
                outline_y = outline_y + 10;
                body_y = body_y + 10;
                eye_y = eye_y + 10;
                outline_position_x = 296;
                body_position_x = 300;

                redraw (score, outline_x, outline_y, outline_position_x, body_x, body_y, body_position_x, life);
                c.fillOval (eye_x+3, eye_y+8, 4, 4); // eye
            }

            if (key_entered == 'p' || key_entered == 'P')
            {   
                c.setColor (Color.blue);
                Font f2 = new Font ("Freestyle Script", Font.BOLD, 56);
                c.setFont (f2);
                c.drawString ("GAME PAUSED", 173, 250);

                for (int i = 1; p == i ; i++)
                {
                    key_entered = c.getChar();
                    p++;

                    if (key_entered == 'p' || key_entered == 'P')
                    {
                        p = 0;
                        background();
                        redraw (score, outline_x, outline_y, outline_position_x, body_x, body_y, body_position_x, life);
                        c.fillOval (eye_x, eye_y, 4, 4); // eye
                    }
                    c.setColor (Color.black);
                }
                p = 1;
            }
            random_number = (int) (Math.random()* 100)+1;

            //point start
            if (run_time == score)
            {
            do
            {
                point_x = (int)(Math.random() * 1000) + 1;
            }

            while (point_x < 65 || point_x > 546);

            do
            {
                point_y = (int)(Math.random() * 1000) + 1;
            }

            while (point_y < 90 || point_y > 430);

            run_time ++;

            }
            c.setColor (Color.green);
            c.fillOval (point_x, point_y, 8, 8);
            // point end

            if (outline_x  > (point_x-32) && outline_x < (point_x+4) && outline_y > (point_y-29) && outline_y < (point_y+7))
            {
                score = score + 1;
            }


            if (outline_x < 59)
            {
                outline_x = 548;
                body_x = 548;
                eye_x = 569;
            }

            if (outline_x > 549)
            {
                outline_x = 60;
                body_x = 60;
                eye_x = 78;
            }

            if (outline_y < 89)
            {
                outline_y = 419;
                body_y = 419;
                eye_y = 425;
            }

            if (outline_y > 420)
            {
                outline_y = 90;
                body_y = 90;
                eye_y = 98;
            }

        }

        while (1 == 1);

    } // main method

    public static void background ()
    {
        c.setColor (new Color (0, 0, 0));
        c.fillRect (0, 0, 640, 500);
        c.setColor (new Color (35, 47, 210)); 
        Font f3 = new Font ("Footlight MT Light", Font.BOLD, 16);
        c.setFont (f3);
        c.drawString ("a = move left", 10, 485);
        c.drawString ("d = move right", 125, 485);
        c.drawString ("s = move down", 255, 485);
        c.drawString ("w = move up", 385, 485);
        c.drawString ("p = pause game", 500, 485);

    }

    public static void redraw (int score, int outline_x, int outline_y, int outline_position_x, int body_x, int body_y, int body_position_x, int life)
    {   
        c.setColor (new Color (0, 0, 0));
        c.fillRect (50, 50, 10, 400); // left border
        c.fillRect (580, 50, 12, 400); // right border
        c.fillRect (50, 450, 540, 15); // bottom border
        c.fillRect (50, 40, 540, 10); // top border
        c.setColor (new Color (35, 47, 210));
        Font f2 = new Font ("Footlight MT Light", Font.BOLD, 45);
        c.setFont (f2);
        c.drawString ("Welcome to Pac-Man", 100, 37);
        c.setColor (new Color (125, 23, 137)); 
        c.fillRect (60, 50, 520, 400);
        Font f3 = new Font ("Footlight MT Light", Font.BOLD, 24);
        c.setFont (f3);
        c.setColor (new Color (0, 0, 0));
        c.drawString("SCORE : " + score, 61, 75);
        c.drawString ("Lives :", 380, 75);
        lives (life);
        c.fillRect (50, 85, 550, 5);// line
        c.setColor (Color.black);// pac man drawing begins
        c.fillArc (outline_x, outline_y, 35, 35, outline_position_x, 320); // outline
        c.setColor (Color.yellow);
        c.fillArc (body_x, body_y, 32, 32, body_position_x, 310); // body
        c.setColor (Color.black);// pac man drawing ends
    }

    public static int lives (int life)
    {
        int x1 = 470;

        for (int i = 1; i <= life; i++)
        {
            c.setColor (Color.black);// pac man drawing begins
            c.fillArc (x1, 55, 30, 30, 26, 320); // outline
            c.setColor (Color.yellow);
            c.fillArc (x1, 55, 28, 28, 30, 310); // body
            c.setColor (Color.black);// pac man drawing begins
            c.fillOval (x1+15, 59, 4, 4); // eye

            x1+=35;
        }
        return life;   
    }

} // Pac_man class
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read your code (Shorten it to the relevant portions to make it more readable), but I feel like you're approaching this the wrong way. You'll probably want to use a [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html). This will allow you to "listen" for keys being pressed concurrently while your program runs.

```
public class KeyEventDemo implements KeyListener {
        typingArea = new JTextField(20);
        typingArea.addKeyListener(this);

    /** Handle the key typed event from the text field. */
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // snip
    }

    /** Handle the key-pressed event from the text field. */
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // snip
    }

    /** Handle the key-released event from the text field. */
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // snip
    }
```

If you have problems with focus, I would recommend also reading [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for an alternative to the KeyListeners.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your teacher made a custom Console class which you are using to draw you pacman game?

I googled "hsa.Console" and found some Javadoc for it.. so assuming I'm this is the Console class you are using: http://www.brentwoodhigh.com/apcs/holt/hsa-javadoc/Console.html

According to your teacher's Javadoc [Console](http://www.brentwoodhigh.com/apcs/holt/hsa-javadoc/Console.html) implements [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) so you can subclass his Console with your own and listen for key events in there.

Example:

```
class MyConsole extends Console {
   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
      super.keyPressed(e); // Call your teacher's code in case he does something
      // set some shared variable with the key that was typed
      // you'll read this shared variable in your main loop
   }
}
```

KeyEvent javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html

In your main you'll do:

```
c = new MyConsole();
```

instead of

```
c = new Console();
```

In your main loop you'll want to poll for the last key that was entered...  Technically you'll need a shared `volatile` variable but I guess your teacher either doesn't know that or is introducing you to threading ridiculously early.

Your file will look something like:

```
// The "Pac_man" class.
import java.awt.*;
import hsa.Console;

public class Pac_man {
   public static volatile char lastChar;
   static Console c;
   public static void main(String [] args) {
       c = new MyConsole();
       do {
          // read whatever character may have been set
          // by the console
          char key = lastChar;
          ...your event loop logic...
       } while (running);
   }
}
static class MyConsole extends Console {
   // this method is called by the system whenever a key has been pressed
   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
      // call your prof's version of keyPressed
      super.keyPressed(e); 

      // set the shared lastChar variable
      Pac_man.lastChar = e.getKeyChar();
   }
}
```

Of course not having access to the library your teacher has made I can only make educated guesses on what'll work.

Comment: Please don't write complete solutions to other people's homework. It does them no favors; pointers in the right direction are much more appropriate.

Comment: My teacher did not make a library, I believe it came with the program "ready to program Java" from http://compsci.ca/holtsoft/, after downloading the program go to file --> new -->hsa consol template, I dont quite understand whats happening in your code...